# zero correlation does not imply independence example

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the two random variables X and Y=(2B-1)X, where X $\sim$ N(0,1) and B$\sim$Bernoulli(1/2) are independence. 
(a) Show that 
$\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y)$
Hence, conclude that both X and Y are normally distributed.
(b) Show that $Corr(X,Y)^2 = \frac{Cov(X,Y)^2}{Var(X)Var(y)}=0\\$.Hence, conclude that X and Y are uncorrelated. Remark However X and Y are not independent.$\\$
$\\$
For part a), i simplified from $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)= \mathbb{P}((2B-1)X \leq y) = \mathbb{P}((2B-1) \leq y)\mathbb{P}(X \leq y)= \mathbb{P}(B \leq \frac{y+1}{2})\mathbb{P}(X \leq y)$ . I know that $\mathbb{P}(B \leq \frac{1}{2})=1 $,but $\mathbb{P}(B \leq \frac{y+1}{2})$ does not equal one when y is negative. How do complete this? From this result, we can say $Y \sim N(0,1)$. For part B, the 2nd part is just the definition of or correlation. Is there a faster way of obtaining the answer, or do i need to use the bivariate normal distribution?
 THank you

Comment: Please select a more suiting title to the question. Zero correlation does **not** imply independence and the question itself denies that it does.

Comment: sorry, it is fixed now

Comment: First step where you pass into hyperspace: why do you believe that $$\mathbb{P}((2B-1)X \leq y) = \mathbb{P}((2B-1) \leq y)\mathbb{P}(X \leq y)\ ?$$

Comment: Xstuds can not notify @Did until you use @ sign.

Comment: @MANMAID good to know

Comment: @Did Yeah you are right. This should be true for the intersection. I got confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(Y\leq y)=P((2B-1)X\leq y)=P((2B-1)X\leq y\mid B=0)P(B=0)+P((2B-1)X\leq y\mid B=1)P(B=1)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big[P(X\geq -y)+P(X\leq y)\Big]=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big[1-\Phi(-y)+\Phi(y)\Big]=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big[2\Phi(y)\Big]=\Phi(y)=P(X\leq y)$.

Since $\Phi(-y)=1-\Phi(y)$, $\Phi$ is cdf of $N(0,1)$

$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E[(2B-1)X^2]-E(X)E[(2B-1)X]=E(2B-1)\big[E(X^2)-(E(X))^2\big]$

Now note that $E(2B-1)=2E(B)-1=1-1=0$

Hence $Cov(X,Y)=0$